# How to update record in ror?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one table employee resignation in which i want to update one column named as settled on date . There is one button in my page when i click on that button one model pop-up on screen for updating the settled on date. But the query which i am using to update is not giving any output.

Form -

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title"><center> Settelment Date </center></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <%= bootstrap_form_for :employee_resignation,url:{action:"settelment_date", id: @employee_resignation.id} do |f| %>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_field :settled_on,label: "Settled On", class: 'settled_on'%>
          </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top:20px;">
        <%= f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-sm btn-warning fa fa-modx' %>

      </div>
    </div>
      <% end %>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer"></div>
</div>
</div>  


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('.settled_on').datepicker({
    changeYear:true,
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: '-1:+150',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

  }); 
</script>
```

Controller code -

```
 def settelment_date
     @settled_on = params[:settled_on]   
     @employee_resignation = EmployeeResignation.find(params[:id])
     @employee_resignation.update_all(settled_on: @settled_on)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing `update_all` only works into collection instances like `ActiveRecord::Relation`

And as you are doing `find`, its only give you `ActiveRecord::Base` instance of `EmployeeResignation`

You need to use `update` for that not `update_all`

```
 @employee_resignation.update(settled_on: @settled_on)
```

Comment: But she submits form via the POST, so wouldn't `@settled_on` be empty or nil?

Comment: How POST submit effect this? But AFA data is coming in `params[:settled_on]`. As question suggest `How to update` then i could not worry on that things.

Comment: @settled_on = params[:settled_on]   i want value in this how i can get ?

Comment: can you share your params in request? can't you see `settled_on` there?

Comment: I just have looked your form. I think `params[:employee_resignation][:settled_on]` is your params

Comment: can you share your params in request?

Comment: (byebug)  @settled_on = params[:settled_on]
nil
(byebug)  @settled_on = params[:employee_resignation][:settled_on]
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

nil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156724/discussion-between-anubhi-golechha-and-jon-snow).